# Samba & Microsoft Access Drop Outs

Tags: networking, samba, microsoft-office

Currently I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server box up and running with samba, following bad practices it currently serves as a primary domain controller and file sharing system. (I know I know, going to a v-sphere based solution soon)

We have a access database with an .accdb file storing all our data (tables only) with all our forms and macro's on the client side. There are around 15-20 users concurrently running the database from the internal LAN at one time.

An error keeps popping up on the client side saying that it access has been disconnected. Multiple users get this error.

I have tried running never ending pings which show no network access interruption when pining the server and no other open applications show network disconnects when access shows the error.

From my reading I know that:

- Access is super sensitive and one dropped packet and the connection will drop
- Other people report problems that 10+ users causes issues others say over 25

I want to move over to either an SQL or MYSQL based solution but the time scale on that is to great for me to jump on it right away.

Has anybody come across similar issues that have an easy fix?
Is there any diagnostic tools I could use to identify the problem?
Should we bite the bullet and looking at migrating to some sort of database application?

Comment: You could install Wireshark on the server and try to identify whether there are network-related issues. I'm not familiar with MS Access, but I doubt it has decent error reporting, so if it's not the network, I'd kick everyone off and bring one person back on at a time until it broke.

Comment: Thanks for  commenting! Weirdly this is the exact troubleshooting I have proposed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes here in the future follow this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122804/network-connection-was-interrupted-error-with-shared-access-database/) to see the answer to the question, the answer in short is that samba doesn't appear to work to well with Access.